# Inheriting data from ancestor documents in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

I'm using RavenDB to store three types of curriculum: Units, Lessons, and Activities. These three types all inherit from CurriculumBase:

```
public abstract class CurriculumBase
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> SubjectAreaIds { get; set; }
    // non-relevant properties removed
}
```

These documents have a hierarchical relationship, so I've modeled the hierarchy as a separate single document as recommended here: [Modelling Hierarchical Data with RavenDB](http://java.dzone.com/articles/modelling-hierarchical-data)

```
public class CurriculumHierarchy
{
    public class Node
    {
        public string CurriculumId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<Node> Children { get; set; }

        public Node()
        {
            Children = new List<Node>();
        }
    }

    public List<Node> RootCurriculum { get; set; }

    public CurriculumHierarchy()
    {
        RootCurriculum = new List<Node>();
    }
}
```

I need to be able to do searches across all curriculum documents. For simple properties, that seems easy enough to do with a multi-map index.

However one of the properties I need to be able to search by (in combination with the other search criteria) is SubjectAreaId. I need to be able to get curriculum for which it *or any of its ancestors* have the specified subject area id(s). In other words, for search purposes, documents should inherit the subjectAreaIds of their ancestors.

I've considered de-normalizing subjectAreaIds, and storing the full calculated set of subjectAreaIds in each document, but that will require updates whenever the hierarchy itself or the subjectAreaIds of any of a given document's ancestors change. I'm hoping this is something I can accomplish with an index, or perhaps an entirely different approach is needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LoadDocument to load the parents during indexing.

http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/indexes/indexing-related-documents

Comment: I was familiar with LoadDocument, but my challenge was making an item's ancestors available to Raven indexing. I've added an answer with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

The main challenge I encountered was that I had written code in CurriculumHierarchy to get a document's ancestors, but this code isn't executable during indexing.

To solve this, I added a read-only property to CurriculumHierarchy which generates a dictionary of ancestors for each document:

```
public Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> AncestorLookup
{
    get
    {
        // Not shown: build a dictionary where the key is an  
        // ID and the value is a list of the IDs for 
        // that item's ancestors
    }
}
```

This dictionary is serialized by Raven and therefore available for indexing.

Then my index ended up looking like this:

```
public class Curriculum_Search : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask
{
    public Curriculum_Search()
    {
        AddMap<Activity>(
            activities =>
                from activity in activities
                let hierarchy = 
                    LoadDocument<CurriculumHierarchy>("curriculum_hierarchy")
                let ancestors = 
                    LoadDocument<CurriculumBase>(hierarchy.AncestorLookup[activity.Id])
                select new
                {
                    subjectAreaIds = ancestors.SelectMany(x => x.SubjectAreaIds).Distinct().Union(activity.SubjectAreaIds),
                });

       // Not shown: Similar AddMap statements for Lessons and Units
    }
}
```

I was a bit concerned about performance, but since there are less than 2000 total curriculum documents, this seems to perform acceptably.